# Laravel Mail: attach if not null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-mail

I am sending emails using the mailable class of Laravel. I want to attach files, if the files exist. So I only want to add the attach parameter if the file exists. I could work with if/else clauses, but I have different files and that would not be clean. A `attachIfNotNull` function (which does not exist) would be helpful in this case, but maybe there are other clean solutions..

```
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.orders.shipped')
                    ->attach('/path/to/file1', [
                        'as' => 'name.pdf',
                        'mime' => 'application/pdf',
                    ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `File::exists()` or `Storage::exists()`:

```
$view = $this->view('emails.orders.shipped');
return \File::exists('/path/to/file1') ? $view
     : $view->attach('/path/to/file1', [
         'as' => 'name.pdf',
         'mime' => 'application/pdf',
     ]);
```